# Will threading help improve efficiency in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My application is supposed to have a "realtime with pause" functionality. The user can pause execution, do some things that modify what's going to happen, then unpause and let stuff happen. Stuff happens at regular intervals as specified by the user, can be slow, can be fast.

My goal at using threading here is to improve performance on multicore systems. The amount of data that the application is supposed to crunch at the time intervals is supposed to be arbitrarily large (I expect lots and lots of loops over collections, modifying object properties and generating random numbers, but precious little disk access). I don't want the application to be constrained by the capacity of a single core, if it can use more to run faster.

Will this actually work this way?

I've run some tests (made a program crunch numbers a lot, and looked at CPU usage during its activity), but it's not really conclusive - usage is certainly in the proximity of 100% on my dual core machine, but hardly ever 100%. Does a single-threaded (main only) Java application use all available cores for computation?

Comment: "My goal at using threading here is to improve performance on multicore systems." <-- well, this will probably improve performance, yes, but the most influential factor for better performance when doing parallel processing is your algorithm for processing data

Comment: Single threaded application does not use all cores, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a single-threaded (main only) Java application use all available cores for computation?

No, it will normally use a single core.

Making a program do computations in parallel with multiple threads may make it faster, but it's not a magical solution for any kind of problem. Whether this is a suitable solution for your program depends on what your program is doing exactly, and if the algorithm can be parallelized. If, for example, you are doing lots of computations where the next computation depends on the result of the previous computation, then making it multi-threaded will not help a lot, because you can't do the computations at the same time - the next one first has to wait for the answer of the previous one. So, you first have to think about what computations in your program could be run in parallel.

Java has a lot of support for multi-threading. You can program with threads directly, or use an [executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html), or use the [fork/join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). Whatever is appropriate depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: OK, so supposing I have a collection of elements which I need to process in some way, but which don't need to access other elements of the same collection, then using threading would be helpful here? I'd need to fire off the threads, then wait for all of them to finish. Which type of threading of those you mentioned is most appropriate here?

Comment: If you're using Java 8 then parallel streams (which Steve Siebert mentioned) are probably easiest, otherwise executor services. If you have to combine the results of all computations into a single, final result, fork/join would be useful.

Comment: I'm using Java 7. I was thinking of making threads have a selector property, which would affect how they iterate over the collections (something like thread N starts at N and does every nrofProcessors-th, skipping other elements of the collection). Good idea, bad idea?

Comment: That's one approach you could take. You could also make for example a queue of work items (for example an `ArrayBlockingQueue`) and have a pool of threads managed by an `ExecutorService`, and each thread would pick items to process from the queue. Have a look at what's available in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: @AbuDhabi It seems you are somewhat new to multithreading. A common trap is to think in threads as opposed to independent jobs. One should focus on the algorithm and how it can be parallelized, that is, subdivided into regions of data, steps in a pipeline or recursive sub-tasks.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a single-threaded (main only) Java application use all available cores for computation?

Not usually, but you could make use of some higher level apis in java that is actually using threads for you and youre not even usinfpg threads directly, more obviousiously fork/join and executors, less obvious the new Streams API on collections (ie parallelStream).

In general, though, to make use of all cores, you need to do some kind of concurrency.  Further...its really hard to just observe you OS monitor to see what is going on (especially with only 2 cores)...your OS has other things going on (trying to manage itself, running your IDE, running crontab, running a browers to post to stackoverflow ;).

Finally, just implementing (concurrency) itself may not help, you have to do it "right" for your code/algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

a java thread will run in a single cpu. to use multiple CPUs, you should have multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that u have to do various tasks using your hand. You will do it slowly using one hand and more effciently using both your hands. Similarly, in java or in any other language multi threading provides the system with many hands. The good news is that you can have many threads to do different tasks. Running operations in a single thread will make the program sluggish and sometimes unresponsive. A good practice is to do long running tasks in a separate thread. For example loading large chunks of data from a database should be processed in a separate thread. Downloading data from the internet should also be processed in a separate thread. What happens if you do long running operations in the main thread? The program HANGS and will become unresponsive till the task gets completed and the user will think that there is someting wrong. I hope you get it